# Telling GCC to tail-call a function

Tags: c, gcc, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

Let's say I've got a C function:

```
unsigned int fact(unsigned int n, unsigned int acc) {
  if(n > 0) return fact(n - 1, n * acc);
  return acc;
}
```

Is there a way to tell GCC to tail call the recursive function, something like

```
unsigned int fact(unsigned int n, unsigned int acc) {
  if(n > 0) return __tail_call(fact, n - 1, n * acc);
  return acc;
}
```

I can make this happen with the `-O2` flag passed to the compiler but I'd like the tail call behavior at lower optimization levels so I can compile more quickly.

The actual function is much more complicated, and I want to use TCO because this makes it explicit which state in an iteration can affect future iterations, and which state is reinitialized each iteration.

EDIT: This was flagged as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785066/is-it-possible-to-force-tail-call-optimization-on-gcc-clang), but that thread a) doesn't have any answers for GCC, and b) isn't about placing something *in the code* to force TCO.

Comment: Apparently something called `-foptimize-sibling-calls` is supposed to "Optimize sibling and tail recursive calls. Enabled at levels -O2, -O3, -Os. ". I haven't tried it.

Comment: Oh, nice, thanks Lundin. I'd still like something in the code to do this because it makes it explicit when TCO is necessary for function. But that definitely is a good-enough solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to force tail call optimization on GCC/Clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785066/is-it-possible-to-force-tail-call-optimization-on-gcc-clang)

Comment: Well, if there is any doubt whether a recursive function get tail call optimized or not, the correct solution is to replace the recursion with a loop. That goes for recursion in general.

Comment: @vaxquis Not a single answer in that link is about gcc though.

Comment: @Lundin true, but one good soul answered it in comments, `You can force GCC to provide TCO with a compiler flag: -foptimize-sibling-calls` ; still, the lack of valid answers doesn't prevent this question from being a duplicate, sadly. Giving a bounty would be IMVHO better than re-asking a question again and again and again (using google through GCC docs & SO would be even better, though). As far as using iteration instead of recursion - 100% agree; as long as the problem is not trivial, there's usually little gain in using recursion in non-purely-functional languages IMO.

Comment: @vaxquis I didn't post it as an answer since I haven't used the option before and don't know how useful/buggy that option is. I merely searched for "tail" in RTFM, and behold...

Comment: @vaxquis I would not say that they are duplicates. That other question asks specifically for enforcing TOC. This question asks for how to enable it without using `-O2`.

Answer (score 2):

as per https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html ,

> `-foptimize-sibling-calls`
>
> Optimize sibling and tail recursive calls.
>
> Enabled at levels -O2, -O3, -Os.

further reading here: [How do I check if gcc is performing tail-recursion optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490324/how-do-i-check-if-gcc-is-performing-tail-recursion-optimization)