# Is there a way to call a function without adding to the call stack?

Tags: c++, recursion, goto

I've some `goto`-laden C++ code that looks like

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void test0()
{
    int i = 0;
loop:
    i++;
    if (i > 10) goto done;
    goto loop;
done:
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I'd like to get rid of the `goto`s while (mostly) **preserving the appearance of the original code**; that more-or-less rules-out `for`, `while` etc. (unless they're hidden behind macros) as that changes the appearance of the existing code too much.  Imagine wanting to minimize the "diffs" between existing code and changed code.

One idea is to use a class with methods:

```
class test1 final
{
    int i = 0;
    void goto_loop()
    {
        i++;
        if (i > 10) goto_done();
        goto_loop();
    }
    void goto_done()
    {
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
public:
    test1() { goto_loop(); }
};
```

This works, but every call to `goto_loop()` adds to the call stack. Is there some way to do an `exec`-like function call? That is, call a function "inline" somehow...execute additional code *without* adding to the call stack?  Is there a way to make tail-recursion explicit?

Using C++20 (or even C++23) is acceptable, although a C++17 solution would be "nice."

---

For all those wondering about "why?" The *real* original code is [BASIC](https://github.com/coding-horror/basic-computer-games) ...

Comment: why no `while` or `for` loop?

Comment: How about `for (int i = 0; ++i <= 10;) { }`?

Comment: sorry, but I dont agree on the drama. Your code looks very much like identical to a `for` loop when unrolled in to `goto` with two labels, hence your version with two functions is the more drastic change imho

Comment: Turning iterative code into recursive code is usually a mistake. That aside, this seems like a pointless change. If you can't do it right, don't do it.

Comment: *"but every call to `goto_loop()` adds to the call stack."*. Not necessary, tail call optimization can apply for that kind of recursion.

Comment: @JackBrown -- The code you write is only a description of what you want the program to do.  The compiler is then free to optimize and change the code in any way it sees fit, as long as the final results are the same, and that includes optimizing the code to do things inline.  Playing around with `goto` is not going to have you "beat the compiler" at the speed game.

Comment: That looks like a do-while loop. Is that a drastic change too?

Comment: @Jarod42 yes...that's what I'm looking for.  Is there a way to make that explicit?

Comment: @JackBrown You've changed a loop based solution into a recursion based solution. In my opinion this is a significantly more intrusive change than changing the `goto` approach into a `for` or `while` loop.

Comment: @JackBrown -- So you are trying to do a line-by-line translation from BASIC to C++?  Well, doing line-by-line translations rarely ever work.  Why not see what the BASIC code does, and when you figure it out, throw the BASIC code away and rewrite it in C++ using proper C++ form and idioms?   Doing line-by-line translations will only result in C++ that is buggy, hard-to-maintain, inefficient, or, in your case, look weird to a C++ programmer.

Comment: Like a band-aid, sometimes you just need to rip it off an move forward.  If you're going to code C++, you should code it like any sane C++ coder would.  That'll make it a lot easier for other C++ developers to work with it in the future.

Comment: If changing the `goto` into a `for` or `while` is too drastic a change, then I recommend leaving the `goto` alone. Legacy code existing is a normal part of an evolving software.

Comment: @JackBrown Is the aesthetics of the code really the deciding metric for this refactor?

Comment: @JackBrown I did notice that in the question. But that context doesn't explain why maintaining the original visual appearance of the code is important.

Comment: @JackBrown How does changing the function to `void test0(){ for (int i = 0; ++i <= 10;) { }  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); }` stop the code from working?

Comment: @JackBrown -- Here is the flaw in all of this:  C++ is **not** BASIC.  Trying to make C++ look like BASIC isn't going to get very far.  Making C++ into spaghetti like the BASIC program shouldn't be the goal of any programmer.

Comment: If I were forced to choose if I'd prefer to implement a for loop with a goto or with a recursion I might choose goto.

Comment: *I'd like to get rid of the gotos while preserving the appearance of the original code*  Then you've set yourself up to fail.  I suggest you discard that notion, and do not try to make C++ look like BASIC.

Comment: `For all those wondering about "why?" The real original code is BASIC` I don't understand how that would answer the "why?". Why does original code being BASIC mean that the appearance should be preserved? I recommend instead reading this advice from the page that you linked to: *"Please DO update for **modern coding conventions**. .. Use **structured programming**. Use subroutines."* This is a loop. Why not write a structured loop?

Comment: @JackBrown -- I'll let you in on an open secret -- C++ code littered with `goto` statements, and then having others look at the code for "bugs" or anything of the sort, reduces the number of persons willing to spend time looking at the code, maybe down to 0.  Let's say you continue on, and you encounter more `goto` statements in the BASIC code, where the logic is basically a tangled mess.  I will be willing to bet that very few, if anyone will volunteer to make sense of C++ code with the same goto "logic", and will instead try to convince you to rewrite the code.

Comment: *Imagine wanting to minimize the "diffs" between existing code and changed code.* -- That only makes sense when comparing two pieces of code written in the same language.  That doesn't make any sense when comparing two totally different languages.  It's like trying to do a "diff" on Spanish and English.

Comment: Invest your time into writing tests. These will help you much more in future than any changes to syntax you could do now. May be less fun though, depending on your attitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to write an `exec()` routine that stops the recursion:

```
template<typename Func>
void exec(const Func& f)
{
    using function_t = Func;
    static std::map<const function_t*, size_t> functions;
    const auto it = functions.find(&f);
    if (it == functions.end())
    {
        functions[&f] = 1;
        while (functions[&f] > 0)
        {
            f();
            functions[&f]--;
        }
        functions.erase(&f);
    }
    else
    {
        functions[&f]++;
    }
}
```

With that utility, I can more-or-less preserve the appearance of the existing code

```
class test4 final
{
    int i = 0;
    void goto_loop_() {
        i++;
        if (i > 10) goto_done(); } 
    void goto_loop() { goto_loop_(); static const auto f = [&]() { goto_loop(); }; exec(f); }
    void goto_done()
    {
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
public:
    test4() { goto_loop(); }
};
```

(Using a lambda avoids hassles with pointers to members functions.)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to [ensure tail call optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785066/is-it-possible-to-force-tail-call-optimization-on-gcc-clang). At present there's no standard way to do this, but if you're using Clang you can [use the `clang::musttail`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67397487/567292) attribute.

Comment: @JackBrown well maybe, or you could use `setjmp`, but that's even worse than `goto`.

Answer (score 1):

Loop might preserve code structure:

```
void test2()
{
    int i = 0;
    for (;;) {
        i++;
        if (i > 10) break;
        continue;
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

even if

```
void test3()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
        /*Empty*/
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

would be more idiomatic (assuming some useful code as the loop is useless actually).